# How to add Countdown Timer in UWP app with Background support?

Tags: c#, windows, timer, uwp

I want to make a countdown Timer of 30 minutes in UWP with background support.
is there is anyway to do that, like this App:

[image]

Here is my app **overview Image**: 
[image]

And I want to Enable Claim button when timer ends.

Comment: Please add some more clarification to your question, also show some code what you have tried and tell where you have encountered problems.

Comment: See my edited post @Romasz

Comment: I'm sorry, but your edit doesn't help me to understand where is the problem.

Comment: i don't code for this right now but i want to add this countdown process with background support. do u have any samples like this?? so that after countdown process the button will be visible or enable for user @Romasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make a countdown Timer of 30 minutes in UWP with background support.

There are possibilities for running code in the background but that takes some doing. And as I read this you only want to enable a button in the end so you shouldn't need and shouldn't use a background task.

As a rough idea, your app should determine the start and/or end time for the button and make sure you persist that when you are suspended.

You should be able to use a normal DispatcherTimer to update the progressbar and the button when your app is active.